# One loop over multiple Ansible Tasks via a variable defined with service names

Tags: ansible

I have the following code with two services defined in the variable "services". My goal is to do ONE loop through the tasks for each service INDIVIDUALLY. My code right now is looping them together which is wrong, I need them to loop through the tasks INDIVIDUALLY (almost like a foreach in Powershell). Please help!

```
---
- hosts: test
  vars:
    services:
      - redcloak
      - DeviceAssociationService
  vars_files:
  - ../windows-vars.yml
  tasks:
   - name: Start service
     win_service: 
       name: "{{ item }}"
       state: started
     loop:
        "{{ services }}"
   - name: Get Service Status
     win_service:
       name: "{{ item }}"
     register: result
     loop:
        "{{ services }}"
   - name: Verify Service Is Running
     debug: msg="running on {{ ansible_hostname }}"
     when: result.state == 'running
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your tasks into a separate task file. Create a file `service_tasks.yaml` with this content:

```
- name: Start {{ service_name }}
  win_service: 
    name: "{{ service_name }}"
    state: started
- name: Get {{ service_name }} Status
  win_service:
    name: "{{ service_name }}"
  register: result
- name: Verify {{ service_name }} Is Running
  debug: msg="running on {{ ansible_hostname }}"
  when: result.state == 'running'
```

And then write your playbook like this:

```
- hosts: test
  vars:
    services:
    - redcloak
    - DeviceAssociationService
  vars_files:
    - ../windows-vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Start all services
      include_tasks:
        file: service_tasks.yaml
      loop: "{{ services }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: service_name
```

When you run your playbook, you should see tasks executed in the following order:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts]
TASK [Start all services]
TASK [Start redcloak]
TASK [Get redcloak Status]
TASK [Verify redcloak Is Running]
TASK [Start DeviceAssociationService]
TASK [Get DeviceAssociationService Status]
TASK [Verify DeviceAssociationService Is Running]
```

---

You could also place your tasks into a [role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) and use the same technique (but with `include_role` instead of `include_task`).

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try and let you know